# Internal Wireless Card setup Mac Dual Boot 2016 Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, network-interface, macintosh, broadcom

I need to install the driver as it was not recognised automatically when installing Kali Linux on my MacBook Pro. If I type `iwconfig` then I get only `lo` and no `wlan0`. There is no ethernet port on the new MacBooks so I needed to find a way to connect to the internet in order to download stuff without using the USB method. I used my phone's connection over Bluetooth.

The following terminal command gives me the Wireless Network Adapter make. I went to [kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers) and looked this up in the Drivers table. It shows that it wasn't supported and I needed to use something called wl.

```
root@kali:~# lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0134]
Kernel modules: bcma
04:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
```

I am having trouble configuring my network card in my MacBook Pro to work on Kali Linux. When I try:

```
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

I get the error:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.248/build/make.log for more information.
```

The other problem some people are having is with:

```
modprobe wl
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache search linux-headers`

Comment: Sure. I've done that and I get the multiple options. I tried installing the first one but got an error message (see discussion please). Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually fixed this by doing the following:

1) Making sure these were in /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

2) Making sure everything was ready

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

3) Rebooting the kernel

```
reboot
```

4) Finding out my version:

```
root@kali:~# uname -a
Linux kali 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

5) Finding out which network card I had

```
root@kali:~# lspci | grep Wireless
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

6) Running this:

```
root@kali:~# apt-get update; apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms; apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

7) Then:

```
root@kali:~# modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

and

```
root@kali:~# sudo modprobe wl
```

Finally you can check that it's worked by using `iwconfig` and you should see that now you have `wlan0` recognised by Kali Linux. Go to settings and connect to wi-fi.